# Unity + Leap Motion: error CS0246 (namespace) issue

Tags: c#, namespaces, unity-game-engine, leap-motion, oculus

We have a Unity 5 program running well with Oculus Rift + Leap Motion on a Windows 7 computer. We tried to have the same program running on another computer with Windows 10, but these following errors showed up.

Could any of you provide some suggestions? Thanks a lot! (ps. Oculus Rift and Leap Motion are running well on the Win10 computer with a separate Unity project: the package called "Core Assets" from Leap Motion that shows both Oculus and Leap Motion connections.)

Thanks!

**The error messages in Unity are:**

Assets/LeapMotion/Scripts/Hands/DebugFinger.cs(14,28): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `FingerModel' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Assets/LeapMotion/Scripts/Hands/PolyFinger.cs(13,27): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `FingerModel' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Assets/LeapMotion/Scripts/Hands/PolyHand.cs(17,25): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `HandModel' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Assets/LeapMotion/Scripts/Hands/RiggedFinger.cs(17,29): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `FingerModel' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Assets/LeapMotion/Scripts/Hands/RiggedHand.cs(12,27): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `HandModel' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Answer (score 0):

The error messages pretty much sum it up: these classes are not present in your project. It seems unlikely that the project on the Win 7 computer is exactly the same as the project on the Win 10 computer -- these are compile errors after all. My guess is that you are using an earlier version of the Leap Motion assets on the computer that works and the Orion version on the other computer. None of the classes shown in the error messages are included in the newer, Orion assets. (Even if you upgraded the assets on the Win 7 computer, it may still contain the older files, and classes that depend on them.)

Comment: Although both computers have the latest Leap Motion driver (Orion), the Unity project (made on the Win7 computer) has these three folders related to Leap Motion: "LeapMotion", "LeapMotionVR", "LeapMotion+OVR". So our challenge now is that we are not entirely sure which of these three folders got Leap Motion working when the the project is running on the Win7 computer, which is also why we cannot sort out which folder/files one we should look into (delete, or add/remove things) so we can solves the errors we posted about it not running on the Win10 computer. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The LeapMotionVR and LeapMotion+OVR folders are from the old assets. The LeapMotion folder was in both. The old assets aren't compatible with the new assets -- you can't mix and match (though some minor scripts might work). If you want to use the Orion assets, you should just fix the project on the Win10 computer by finding and removing the references to the missing classes (as a start, there will probably be more errors that pop up after you do that).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Leap Motion company made a mistake releasing the Unity SDK. They build it in the wrong framework. You may be able to run the project in unity but not to debug it with Visual Studio.

The company said that they will release an update of the SDK without any problems, we'll have to wait. Until that moment you can keep coding and use the Debug.Log function to debug at real time.

You can find more info in here:

https://community.leapmotion.com/t/cannot-compile-unity-c-script-if-i-use-leap-motion-orion-4-1-3/5514